# Loading a random UIViewController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller

I would like to pick a random UIViewController from a stored list of view controllers to load after one has finished. Yes, it needs to be a UIViewController and not just a UIView. I'm thinking I could do this with a .plist, but how would I go from the string name of a view controller to the actual view controller object name?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To create an instance of a class from a name, you can use:

```
UIViewController* object = (UIViewController*)[[NSClassFromString(@"NameofClass") alloc] init];
```